# How to display multiple data from local storage

Tags: html, json, forms, local-storage

I'm trying to keep the data saved on the submit.html page. The data is being stored on localstorage, i want the entered data to be in the table for always whenever i visit that page. Currently it is visible on the time of submit event only. when i go back to submit.html page with another entry, the previous data was gone.

Here's the code:
1, index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css" />
  <title>Save Later</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="alert"></div>
  <form id="save-later-form" action="result.html" onsubmit="callme()" method="POST">
    <h3>Simple Save Later Form</h3>
    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="Email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
    <div class="inline" style="display: flex; ">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
        <label for="First name"><b>First name</b></label>
        <input id="Firstname" type="text" placeholder="First name" name="First name" required>
      </div>
      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin-left:320px;">
        <label for="Last name"><b>Last name</b></label>
        <input id="Lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last name" name="Last name" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <label for="Business"><b>Business</b></label>
    <select id="Business" name="Business">
      <option value="Food & Beverage">Food & Beverage</option>
      <option value="Restaurants">Restaurants</option>
      <option value="Pet Shops">Pet Shops</option>
      <option value="Fashion Boutique">Fashion Boutique</option>
    </select>
    <label for="Description">Description</label>
    <textarea name="Description" id="Description" placeholder="Describe yourself in 100 words"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    <button type="submit" id="save">SAVE</button>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

2, Index.JS

```js
function getData() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data') || "[]");
}

function callme() {
  const data = getData();
  const obj = Object.assign(...["Email", "Firstname", "Business"].map(prop =>
    ({
      [prop]: document.getElementById(prop).value
    })));
  localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data.concat(obj)));
}
```

3, Result.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Detail Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>User Detail Page</h1>
  <div id="result-table">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Email</td>
        <th>Firstname</td>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Business</td>
        <th>Description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="first"></td>
        <td id="second"></td>
        <td id="third"></td>
        <td id="fourth"></td>
        <td id="fifth"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
  </div>

  <script>
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('first').innerText  = localStorage.getItem('Email');
  document.getElementById('second').innerText = localStorage.getItem('Firstname');
  document.getElementById('third').innerText  = localStorage.getItem('Lastname');
  document.getElementById('fourth').innerText = localStorage.getItem('Business');
  document.getElementById('fifth').innerText  = localStorage.getItem('Description');
};
  </script>
  <form action="/index.html">
    <button>Go Back</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I managed to save data to local storage as JSON, but cannot parse multiple data to Result page, currently if resubmitted, data would be overwritten rather than adding new to table. Please any help is appreciated
[image]

Result page:

Comment: localStorage data are linked only to one page

Comment: @MisterJojo how can I parse those array object from local to result page? I did try several function but still not work...

Comment: You cannot. `index.html` and `Result.html` are 2 different page, and also 2 different localStorage places, each one canot be read by the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put everything in only one page, as follow:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> your title </title>
  <style>
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  }
body.onForm  table,
body.onTable form  { display: none }

label {
  display       : block;
  margin-bottom : .2rem;
  }
label b {
  display   : block;
  font-size : .8rem;
  }
label textarea {
  width  : 20rem;
  height : 5rem; 
  }
table {
  background-color: darkslategrey;
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 1px;
  margin           : 1rem;
  }
table caption {
  padding      : .4rem;
  caption-side : bottom;
  text-align   : right;
  }
th {
  background-color : #7cc0e7;
  padding          : .2rem .3rem;
  }
td {
  background-color : white;
  padding          : .2rem .3rem;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body class="onForm">

<form name="save-later-form">
  <label>
    <b>Email</b>
    <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Enter Email"required value="">
  </label>
  <label>
    <b>First name</b>
    <input type="text" name="Firstname" placeholder="First name" required value="">
  </label>
  <label>
    <b>Last name</b>
    <input type="text" name="Lastname" placeholder="Last name" required value="">
  </label>
  <label>
    <b>Business</b>
    <select name="Business">
      <option value="Food & Beverage" > Food & Beverage  </option>
      <option value="Restaurants"     > Restaurants      </option>
      <option value="Pet Shops"       > Pet Shops        </option>
      <option value="Fashion Boutique"> Fashion Boutique </option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>
    <b>Description</b>
    <textarea name="Description" placeholder="Describe yourself in 100 words"></textarea>
  </label>
  <button type="reset" > reset    </button>
  <button type="submit"> Submit   </button>
  <button type="button" id="go-Table-Btn"> go 2 table </button>
</form>

<table id="t-business">
  <caption><button id="go-form-Btn"> go 2 form</button></caption>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Email</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Business</th><th>Description</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
</table>
  <script>
const 
  saveLaterForm = document.forms['save-later-form']
, goTableBtn    = document.querySelector('#go-Table-Btn')
, goFormBtn     = document.querySelector('#go-form-Btn')
, ElmsOrder     = ['Email','Firstname','Lastname','Business','Description']
, ls_business   = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('ls_business') || '[]')
, tBusinessB    = document.querySelector('#t-business tbody')
  ;
saveLaterForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()
  let formInputs = Object.fromEntries( new FormData(saveLaterForm).entries() ) 
  ls_business.push(formInputs)
  addRow( formInputs )
  localStorage.setItem('ls_business',JSON.stringify(ls_business))
  document.body.classList.replace('onForm','onTable')
  saveLaterForm.reset()
  }

for (let lsRow of ls_business) addRow( lsRow )

function addRow( elms )
  {
  let row = tBusinessB.insertRow()
  for (let elName of ElmsOrder) row.insertCell().textContent = elms[elName]
  } 

goTableBtn.onclick =_=> document.body.classList.replace('onForm','onTable')
goFormBtn.onclick  =_=> document.body.classList.replace('onTable','onForm')

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, it works, though some lines I not fully comprehend yet, think I need research more. Thankss again